# why does the outline buttons class show me only gray color?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the outline buttons class(btn btn-outline-primary) in bootstrap but for some reason, all the buttons aren't colored at all I only see them as gray here what I am mean
this is how buttons should look like: https://ibb.co/ChKf83y
but here is how they look for me: https://ibb.co/8X1nHSn
here is the code:

```
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>toggle</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
    #p {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <button  id="p" class="btn btn-outline-warning ">Random Videos</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Success</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `btn-outline` class too, along with your remaining classes, like `class=btn btn-outline btn-outline-primary`, and try to post essential code snippets too for a better insight on your work.

Comment: thanks for the reply but sadly it didn't work

Comment: can you show me the css files that have you included?

Comment: here is the whole file https://ibb.co/84L1mYL

Comment: If you can just add the code example in some kind of sandbox, it would be easier to reproduce & look into (instead of a screenshot)

Comment: i updated the question to include the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap 3 and outline buttons were introduced in Bootstrap 4. You can either upgrade to Bootstrap 4 or use CSS instead.

Comment: how to update to bootstrap 4?

Comment: If you can upgrade, use the latest bootstrap 5. Check the documentation, you just have to change the links. [Bootstrap 5 doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/)